# forcing yes for EULA acceptance when installing package via apt-get

Tags: apt

I'm attempting to install a package, thus:

```
apt-get install --yes --force-yes mssql-tools
```

Despite the fact I have done everything I can to get it to accept Yes when prompting for acceptance of the EULA, it hangs on the [Yes/No] prompt for accepting the EULA.

Does anyone know how I can force yes at the EULA prompt.

Comment: See [the manpage for the `yes` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/yes.1.html). Specifically, read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/805324/1438484) to a closely related question. Tl;dr `yes | apt-get install --yes --force-yes mssql-tools`

Comment: When the Microsoft EULA comes up in character mode, press the TAB key - that will highlight the <OK> in red. Press ENTER and it will bring up another screen with <Yes> and <No>, with <No> highlighted in red. Press TAB again to switch the highlight to the <Yes>, then press ENTER to accept the EULA.

Answer (score 2):

This is what everntually worked for me, I found this in the Dockerfile for the mssql-tools image:

```
apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
```